# how to get year month day from date type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I am using Angular 7 and I find difficult to get the year month and day in Date type variable. Also i am using Bootstrap 4. Can you help me please

My html code is

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Check date</label>
      <input type="date" id="user1" formControlName="search_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter date">
</div>
```

and .ts file is

```
ngOnInit() {
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  emp_type: '',
  designation: '',
  week_month: '',
  search_date: Date
});
```

}

```
var yer = this.searchForm.value.search_date
console.log(yer.getUTCMonth())
```

then it will show en error

```
TypeError: yer.getUTCMonth is not a function
at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.onsubmit (home.component.ts:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `input` is not a `Date` type. You need to create one.

Try this:

```ts
var yer = new Date(this.searchForm.value.search_date)
console.log(yer.getUTCMonth())
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
var day = yer.getDay();
var month = yer.getMonth();
var year = yer.getFullYear();
```